# Can someone please write a blog post about Schengen visas?

Tags: discussion, blog

What's happening with the blog, eh mods? ;) (It's fun to yell when I'm no longer responsible ;)).

Anyway, I'm so not the expert on this topic, but we have soo many about Schengen visas, it'd be nice if someone was good enough to write an exhaustive piece on Schengen visas, which we could proof-read happily, and then have as the first blog post on the site.

That way we could repeatedly refer to it in the future as well, and it'd be a handy educational reference for the rest of us trying to help in answering those pesky Schengen visa questions.

MTCW.

Comment: Participation always welcome, Mark ;-) In all seriousness, we should revisit the blog idea and see where we stand in terms of participation. Expect a meta post soon.