# Schengen overview community wiki to avoid duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions, statistics, community-wiki

We are getting a lot of visa questions here and the high number of already existing questions and answers makes it hard to keep track at times.

My feeling after being on the site for a while is that user @GayotFow does an excellent job at keeping the UK-visa questions sorted, due to extraordinary commitment for this site.

For Schengen visa question there are similarly highly-engaged users on here (and thanks, applause and +1s for them from me) but I do recently get the feeling that we are not answering Schengen visa questions as efficiently as we could.

- I see a lot of questions that get answered even though very likely there is a duplicate for them already out there somewhere.
- On the other hand some questions get closed as duplicates even though they do not really answer the closed question.

I have tried pointing out so in comments and chat recently but I am no expert myself and often get lost or don't have the time.

Therefore, should we **create a community wiki answer to this question that lists the most frequently asked Schengen questions and the canonical answers to them so that we can easily and quickly close new questions as duplicates.**?

Below I will post a meager start and invite everyone to contribute to this post.

[Related discussions on closing as duplicates are plenty on here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3638/32134) and [I invite everyone to be careful when closing as dupes.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3644/32134)

There had been [a request for a blog post as far back as 2013](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1363/32134) that never took off, to my knowledge. [This post here (also from 2013) is much related](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1379/32134) and could be a good starting point for further CW entries.

**Edit**: [It has been suggested in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30675276#30675276) to justify the premise for this suggestion quantitatively. Below is a plot that shows the number of Questions tagged [schengen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen) since the beginning of time and the number of such questions closed as duplicates.

[image]

You might marvel at the seasonal effect but the message here is that we get up to 75 Schengen questions a month (possibly more since bad questions might never get tagged correctly) and close on average 30% of those as duplicates. Searching for a good dupe can be cumbersome among the 1,444 questions tagged [schengen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen) as of right now and therefore the suggested community wiki answer.

Comment: By my interpretation this proposal is ass-about-face to the one given here http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/adding-detail-to-existing-encyclopedic-questions-a-proposal which you have endorsed.

Comment: @GayotFow might look like irony but my position still is "I'm in principle pro-canonicals but in that case I feel like the canonical should address the new Q **before** closing". The proposal you link to is about closing Qs with dupes that do not answer them (yet), the idea here is to give an overview of good posts, you could also just use these posts as a resource to cite from as well as to dupe-close.

Comment: This one is supported by HARD evidence, the other is not. So the community is more likely to accept this proposal before the other one. If this proposal carries, I will happily jump on board.

Comment: what is happening with this?

Comment: If the questions are truly identical in meaning, and neither has an answer, shouldn't one of them be closed anyway (with a redirection to the other)?  If they are not identical, but are similar (OFTEN the case for alleged duplicates), perhaps one should be closed and the other edited to cover both questions.

Comment: @JonathanReez Worth adding this to the list of duplicates? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport to the list of duplicates?

Comment: @Traveller definitely. Feel free to add anything that has at least three duplicate questions.

Answer (score 20):

Suggested Syntax:
`**Question**`
 `- [link to dupe] (possibly comments)`

**Where should I apply?**

- [Can I apply for a Schengen visa at a country where I'm not a citizen? If so, under what conditions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72391/32134)
- [Schengen visa appointments not available for 3 months. What are my options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96308/schengen-c-visa-appointments-not-available-for-3-months)

**Application requirements**

- [What is the minimum bank balance for getting a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/bank-balance-for-getting-a-schengen-visa)
- [How recent should my bank statement be when applying for a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50539/how-recent-should-my-bank-statement-be-when-applying-for-a-short-term-visa)
- [Is a bank statement needed to apply for a German visa if I have an invitation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77666/is-a-bank-statement-needed-to-apply-for-a-german-visa-if-i-have-an-invitation)
- [What are the options when a Schengen visa application is in processing after the proposed travel date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/what-are-the-options-when-a-schengen-visa-application-is-in-processing-after-the)
- [How do I ask for a long validity Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181751/how-do-i-ask-for-long-validity-schengen-visa)
- [Paying Schengen visa for a friend](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116208/paying-schengen-visa-for-a-friend)
- [Schengen visa for leisure purposes after attending a conference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77602/schengen-visa-for-leisure-purposes)
- [Do I need a transit visa for Norway if I have a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183377/do-i-need-transit-visa-if-i-have-schengen-visa)
- [Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing)

**Calculation of days**

- [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)
- [How are days of stay calculated for Schengen visas issued for less than 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76624/9009)
- [Do layovers count in the 90-in-180 Schengen rule?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65960/9009)
- [Long-term visa expiration + Count towards Schengen tourist days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67988/work-visa-expiration-count-towards-schengen-tourist-days)

**Requirements for entry**

- [Can I travel through the Schengen area if my passport expires in less than 6 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88021/can-i-travel-through-the-schengen-area-if-my-passport-expires-in-less-than-6-mon/)
- [Can you enter the Schengen area without a return ticket?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24730/one-way-usa-to-switzerland-without-a-return-ticket)
- [Entering the Schengen area 12 days before my visa expires](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50433/entering-the-schengen-area-12-days-before-my-visa-expires)
- [Can airlines deny boarding if my port of entry is different than the country which issued the Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47970/can-airlines-deny-boarding-if-my-port-of-entry-is-different-than-the-country-whi)
- [What conditions need to be fulfilled to enter the Schengen zone visa free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103019/what-conditions-are-required-to-enter-the-schengen-zone-visa-free)
- [Can I use the valid Schengen visa in old passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport)

**Traveling within the Schengen area**

- [Can a non-EU citizen travel freely within the Schengen area without passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139316/can-a-non-eu-citizen-travel-within-schengen-zone-freely-without-passport)
- [Can I travel within the Schengen area if I currently don't have a valid visa or residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76180/traveling-within-schengen-while-waiting-for-a-residence-permit)
- [Can I travel within the Schengen area without a passport if I have my residency permit card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/traveling-inside-europe-without-a-passport-as-a-chinese-person-with-residency-in)
- [Is it obligatory to have a return/onward ticket while traveling between Schengen member states?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90951/is-it-obligatory-to-have-a-return-onward-ticket-while-traveling-between-schengen)
- [Can I visit other Schengen countries on a long-term Schengen visa or residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/can-i-visit-other-schengen-countries-on-a-long-term-type-d-schengen-visa)

**Switching from long-term visas to short-term ones and vice-versa**

- [How to switch from Resident visa to Tourist visa status in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-to-tourist-status-in-the-schengen-area)
- [Do I have to leave the Schengen area if I have a short term (C) visa that will expire right before my National Visa (D) officially starts?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87436/do-i-have-to-leave-the-schengen-area-if-i-have-a-short-term-c-visa-that-will-e)

**EU Family Member visas**

- [Travel on a Schengen visa stating EEA family member without spouse?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/travel-on-a-schengen-visa-stating-eea-family-member-without-spouse)
- [Does a non-EU Spouse of a UK national need a visa to visit the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48970/does-a-non-eu-spouse-of-a-uk-national-need-a-visa-to-visit-the-schengen-area)

**Changes of itinerary (within same country)**

- [Can I change my flight dates after I get my Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45800/can-i-change-my-flight-dates-after-i-get-my-schengen-visa)

**Country that issued my visa vs. countries I'm actually visiting**

- [At which embassy should I apply for a Schengen visa when staying a few days in several countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39468/32134)
- [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13362/32134)
- [Can I travel to Paris for a day with a single entry visa for Schengen from Switzerland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14692/32134) (Can you visit other Schengen countries on a single-entry visa)
- [Does a multiple-entry Schengen visa allow visiting other Schengen countries later, without going via the issuing country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9646)
- [Can I use my single entry Schengen visa to go to a different Schengen country than originally planned?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68666/32134) (Same, but for **single entry** visa)
- [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26939/32134)
- [Can I apply for a Schengen visa at a consulate of a country I don't really intend to visit? Is such visa shopping acceptable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91698/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-at-a-consulate-of-a-country-i-dont-really-inten)
- [Staying fewer days in a Schengen visa approved country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144241/staying-fewer-days-in-a-schengen-visa-approved-country)

**Transiting through the Schengen area**

- [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30569/32134)
- [Does one need a visa to transfer between two airports during a transit through the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84246/does-one-need-a-visa-to-transfer-between-two-airports-during-a-transit-through-t)
- [Is a Schengen visa/transit visa required for a transit flight through two Schengen airports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-a-transit-flight-through-two-scheng)
- [Can I use my German Transit Visa to transit in Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93149/can-i-use-my-german-transit-visa-to-transit-in-netherlands)
- [Do holders of refugee documents need a transit visa for the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93602/do-holders-of-canadian-refugee-documents-need-a-transit-visa-for-the-schengen-ar/94516#)
- [Can I enter the Schengen area with a German long-term visa through a different country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130204/can-i-enter-the-schengen-area-with-a-german-long-term-visa-through-a-different-c)
- [Where do you go through passport control when transiting through another Schengen airport on your way out of the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133452/where-do-you-go-through-passport-control-when-transiting-through-another-schenge)

**Can I arrive the night before and wait airside until I pass through immigration?**

- [Arriving at night before Schengen visa valid date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46211/32134) (for FRA)
- [Arriving in Zurich the night before Schengen visa validity begins](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72111/32134)
- [Can I take a flight that departs after midnight of the day my Schengen visa expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44623/german-short-term-visa-take-flight-next-day-on-visa-expiry-date) (the reverse - depart a few hours after visa expires)

**Visa refusals**

- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)
- [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52782/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) (similar to above, different formulae)
- [Schengen visa refused from German embassy “intention to leave could not be ascertained”](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy-intention-to-leave-could-not-be-ascer)
- [Is changing your passport a good strategy for removing a negative immigration history in Schengen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67808/is-changing-your-passport-a-good-strategy-for-removing-a-negative-immigration-hi)
- [Schengen visa refusal on threat to public policy, security, health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health-germany)
- [Schengen tourist visa refused due to date mismatch. Can I appeal for reconsideration?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20849/schengen-tourist-visa-refused-can-i-appeal-for-reconsideration)
- [Can I get a Schengen visa to visit Estonia if previously my German visa was refused?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10345/can-i-get-a-schengen-visa-to-visit-estonia-if-previously-my-german-visa-was-refu)

**Overstaying**

- [I have a Schengen visa valid for longer than my allowed duration of stay. Can I ignore the duration and overstay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72395/i-have-a-schengen-visa-can-i-overstay)
- [Should I follow what was mentioned in the “duration of stay” or in the "validity of the visa"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51221/32134)
- [Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days)
- [What are the consequences of a US citizen overstaying a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-us-citizen-overstaying-a-schengen-visa)
- [My cancelled flight caused me to overstay my visa and now my visa application was rejected](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182647/my-cancelled-flight-caused-me-to-overstay-my-visa-and-now-my-visa-application-wa)

**Multiple Schengen visas at the same time / Overlapping Schengen visa**

- [I have been issued an overlapping Schengen Visa, would there be an issue?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72204/32134)
- [Can I apply for two Schengen visas if I have two subsequent trips within a short period?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91800/can-i-apply-for-two-schengen-visas-if-i-have-two-subsequent-trips-within-a-short)
- [Are there any rule changes to using a Schengen visa in an expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94695/are-there-any-rule-changes-to-using-a-schengen-visa-in-an-expired-passport)

**Using visas from other countries to enter the Schengen area**

- [Can you enter the Schengen area with a UK visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77159/are-uk-and-schengen-visitor-visas-interchangeable)
- [Do I need a Schengen transit visa as a US Green Card holder?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89276/do-i-need-a-schengen-visa-as-a-us-green-card-holder/89277#89277)

**Using Schengen visas to enter other countries**

- [Which are the non Schengen countries that allow entry for Schengen visa holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders)
- [Visa for Serbia, Bulgaria and Romania](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88086/visa-for-serbia-bulgaria-and-romania)

**Getting a Schengen visa but not using it**

- [Does being granted a Schengen visa and not going have any consequences?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/does-being-granted-a-schengen-visa-and-not-going-have-any-consequences)

**Getting a multiple-entry for two separate trips to the Schengen area**

- [Applying for a Schengen visa when there is a gap between trips to main destination and country of entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66554/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-when-there-is-a-gap-between-trips-to-main-destinati)
- [How to fill questions 25, 29 and 30 for Multi entry Schengen visa form](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25091/how-to-fill-questions-25-29-and-30-for-multi-entry-schengen-visa-form)
- [Entering Schengen area twice within 90 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42495/entering-schengen-area-twice-within-90-days)
- [Going to Italy for 2 days then back to UK for 4 days then to France for 2 weeks. Which embassy should I apply to for my Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17536/going-to-italy-for-2-days-then-back-to-uk-for-4-days-then-to-france-for-2-weeks)
- [Schengen visa for two subsequent short trips: One visa or two?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/schengen-visa-for-two-subsequent-short-trips-one-visa-or-two)
- [Visiting two Schengen countries, coming back home in between, do I apply for single-entry or multiple-entry visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/visiting-two-schengen-countries-coming-back-home-in-between-do-i-apply-for-sin)
- [Can I get a multi-entry Schengen visa if travelling to two different countries on two separate trips?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55729/can-i-get-a-multi-entry-schengen-visa-if-travelling-to-two-different-countries-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Schengen visa for separate 1-week travels with 3 months in-between](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74642/schengen-visa-for-separate-1-week-travels-with-3-months-in-between)

**Schengen residents**

- [Can I return to the Schengen area without my residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105466/can-i-return-to-the-schengen-area-without-my-residency-permit)
- [Travel in the Schengen area with only Carta d'identita and Permesso di soggiorno?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/travel-in-the-schengen-area-with-only-carta-didentita-and-permesso-di-soggiorno)

**Schengen Microstates**

- [Does time spent in non-Schengen European microstates count against
  the available 90-day Schengen time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/does-time-spent-in-non-schengen-european-microstates-count-against-the-available)
- [Countries with no visa requirements on its visitors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6946/countries-with-no-visa-requirements-on-its-visitors)

**Statistics about the Schengen area members**

- [Which embassy will most likely provide a multiple entry Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/which-embassy-will-most-likely-provide-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa)
- [Why is there such a huge difference in refusal rates on Schengen Visa between countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37096/why-is-there-such-a-huge-difference-in-refusal-rates-on-schengen-visa-between-co)

Comment: @pnuts feel free to move it

Comment: Hello? Why isn't this ball rolling?  The site is 6+ years old and we are still answering one-dimensional Schengen enquiries. Uncool. What's happening here on this proposal?

Comment: @JonathanReez https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/80445 — once my edit is accepted, I suggest removing the list from meta to avoid desynchronization.

Comment: @Gilles edit approved, but I'd rather keep it in Meta for easier collaboration

Answer (score 6):

Core documents to be used as part of answering questions:

- [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN) - explains the rules for issuing Schengen visas
- [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399) - spells out nuances related to crossing the Schengen border
- [Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification
  of issued visas](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) — List of official recommendations for consulates issuing Schengen visas
- [Reference amounts required for the crossing of the external border fixed by national authorities](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2023-06/handbook-annex-25_en.pdf) - list of subsistence requirements by country
- [Short stay visa calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en) - calculator of days remaining under 90/180 day rule
- [ETIAS requirements for travel to Europe](https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en) - official ETIAS travel authorisation website
- [List of Czech embassies](http://www.mzv.cz/jnp/en/diplomatic_missions/czech_missions_abroad/). Usually well-designed and lists detailed information on visa requirements for each specific country