# UK visas overview community wiki to avoid duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions, community-wiki

We are getting a lot of UK visa questions here and the high number of already existing questions and answers makes it hard to keep track at times. Let's create a community wiki to track all the canonical questions which can be used to close-vote repeating questions, similar to the [Schengen one](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates).

I've created two community wiki answers below, please feel free to extend them.

Comment: @pnuts filtering what by tags? I don't understand. Filter out to find the canonical UK visa questions? Or to delete duplicates?

Comment: @pnuts I will slowly go over the visa-refusal + uk tagged Qs and try to clean them up. Although the circumstances are so wildly different it's hard to find good canonicals.

Comment: @pnuts ok, Titles cleanup is done, but I still feel like it's a mess. But I do have a better idea. Let's discuss tomorrow in the new chat room I've created.

Comment: Application decision
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126026/what-does-this-mean-your-uk-visa-application-has-been-issued

Comment: Common format residence permit https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34164/uk-visa-exemptions-residence-permit-eea

Comment: @Traveller likewise feel free to add those!

Answer (score 4):

Suggested Syntax:
`**Question**`
 `- [link to dupe] (possibly comments)`

**Visa requirements at application stage**

- [Transit visa to UK required if I already have valid business visa for UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/transit-visa-to-uk-required-if-i-already-have-valid-business-visa-for-uk)
- [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)
- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)
- [What details should a good cover letter contain to back up a UK Visit Visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/what-details-should-a-good-cover-letter-contain-to-backup-a-uk-visit-visa-applic)
- [How to avoid getting a visa refusal when applying for a UK visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55802/how-to-avoid-getting-a-visa-refusal-when-applying-for-a-uk-visitor-visa)
- [Is it possible to apply for a UK visa without being a local resident?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76583/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-a-uk-visa-without-being-a-local-resident)
- [What supporting documents should I include in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92740/what-supporting-documents-should-i-include-in-my-uk-visa-application)
- [What does this mean? "Your UK visa application has been issued"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126026/what-does-this-mean-your-uk-visa-application-has-been-issued)
- [Requirements for long-term UK Standard Visitor Visa (2, 5, 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years/101413#101413)

**Questions about the application form**

- [Proof of address for UK visa applications and correcting clerical errors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91059/proof-of-address-for-uk-visa-applications-and-correcting-clerical-errors)
- [UK Standard visitor visa type for Tourism or Family?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101099/uk-standard-visitor-visa-type-for-tourism-or-family)
- [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas)

**Traveling with dependants**

- [What visa does my wife need to travel to the UK with me, if I'm going there on a business visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39542/taking-wife-on-visitor-visa-while-i-am-on-business-visa-uk?rq=1)
- [How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas)

**Visa refusals**

Central canonical question: [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

1. Provenance of funds

- [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)
- [My application was refused due to 'lack of evidence of funds', are there hidden requirements for UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51849/are-there-hidden-requirements-in-uk-visa-applications-my-application-was-refuse)
- [Standard Visitor Visa refusal grounds V 4.2 (e) (opacity)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94002/standard-visitor-visa-refusal-grounds-v-4-2-e-opacity)

2. Trips sponsored by other people

- [What should a sponsor tell the ECO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco)
- [UK visitor visa refused (multiple sponsors)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73404/uk-visitor-visa-refused-multiple-sponsors)

3. Criminal convictions

- [UK Family Visitor Visa refused on account of having a criminal conviction, however I've never actually had one. What are my options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73243/uk-family-visitor-visa-refused-on-account-of-having-a-criminal-conviction-howev)

4. Lack of ties

- [UK visitor visa refused due to previously staying for too long and not having strong ties. How should I reapply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/uk-visitor-visa-refused-due-to-previously-staying-for-too-long-and-not-having-st)
- [What exactly does the UK Consulate mean by "change of application circumstance"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/what-exactly-does-the-uk-consulate-mean-by-change-of-application-circumstance)

5. Wrong information on application form

- [UK visa refused under 3.6 a of Appendix V (deception)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101247/uk-visa-denied-under-3-6-a-of-appendix-v)

**Returning to the UK after problems with UK immigration**

- [How to return to the UK as a non-visa national after previously experiencing problems at the border?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105689/how-to-return-to-the-uk-as-a-non-visa-national-after-previously-experiencing-pro/105709)

**Entry denial**

- [Refused entry and UK visit visa cancelled because intended length of stay went from 3 weeks to 5 months](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry)

**Accompanied visas (minors)**

- [I am a minor with a UK Accompanied visa. Will I be allowed to travel without my parent, who is already in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64525/i-am-a-minor-with-a-uk-accompanied-visa-will-i-be-allowed-to-travel-without-my)
- [Child Accompanied Visa - can you return with another adult?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44561/child-accompanied-visa-can-you-return-with-another-adult)
- [Can a child enter the UK on an accompanied visa and then leave the country alone?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/can-a-child-enter-the-uk-on-an-accompanied-visa-and-then-leave-the-country-alone)

**Using other visas to enter the UK**

- [Can I enter the UK with a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98249/can-i-enter-the-uk-with-a-schengen-visa)
- [UK visa exemptions residence permit EEA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34164/uk-visa-exemptions-residence-permit-eea)
- [Implications in crossing the Ireland/Northern Ireland land border for an American](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68718/implications-in-crossing-the-ireland-northern-ireland-land-border-for-an-america)
- [What do non-EU/Schengen citizens need to do when travelling within the Common Travel Area (CTA)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr)
- [Travelling through UK, what is considered a "common format residence permit"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143203/travelling-through-uk-what-is-considered-a-common-format-residence-permit)
- [Are Italian residents exempt from needing a UK direct airside transit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36116/uk-visa-direct-airside-transit-visa-indian-national-having-permesso-di-soggiorn)

Answer (score 3):

Core documents to be used as part of answering questions:

- [Immigration Rules Appendix V: visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)
- [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf)
- https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area

Comment: The 'hidden requirements' link is very helpful; glad to see it listed