# US visas overview community wiki to avoid duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions, community-wiki

We see quite a few questions on B1-B2 visas, would it be helpful to create a community wiki along the lines of the existing wikis for Schengen and the UK?

[Schengen overview community wiki to avoid duplicates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates)

[UK visas overview community wiki to avoid duplicates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/uk-visas-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates)

Comment: It would definitely be helpful and could be done as an answer to this very question :)

Comment: @JonathanReez Ok, I will work on drafting an answer for input from the US experts amongst us (of which I am not one!). It may take me a wee while :-)

Comment: Go ahead and then post the draft here so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @JonathanReez Ok, I’ve taken this as far as I can without input from others. From setting up the draft I’ve realised that there are less true duplicates on US visas than there are for Schengen/UK, so I’m not sure if the wiki will 100% fulfil its original objective. Having said that, I think it will still be useful as a point of reference. So, a couple of questions 1) How do I get the draft reviewed by users with expertise in US-related visas? 2) Should that review include checking that the answer is still current and updating where applicable? 3) If approved, how does the wiki get published?

Comment: No review is needed as anyone can just go on the wiki and edit your answer - that's the beauty of StackExchange :) Just make it a community wiki to encourage that.

Answer (score 4):

**1 ESTA and VWP**

[What is the US Visa Waiver Program and what is an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66243/what-is-the-us-visa-waiver-program-and-what-is-an-esta)

[In practice, what is the distinction between ESTA and visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119431/in-practice-what-is-the-distinction-between-esta-and-visas)

[Official ESTA application website and are the others scams?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52406/official-esta-application-website-and-are-the-others-scams)

[Dual Citizenship but I only have one passport — how to use ESTA website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51579/dual-citizenship-but-i-only-have-one-passport-how-to-use-esta-website/51583#51583)

[My ESTA has been refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139594/my-esta-has-been-refused)

[ESTA validity after a visa denial](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139058/esta-validity-after-a-visa-denial)

[Any documents to show when entering USA with ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135928/any-documents-to-show-when-entering-usa-with-esta)

[Are these intended activities legal to do in the USA under the VWP?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140895/are-these-intended-activities-legal-to-do-in-the-usa-under-the-vwp)

[Working in the USA for living expenses only; allowed on VWP?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139485/working-in-the-usa-for-living-expenses-only-allowed-on-vwp)

[Is volunteer work allowed in the US while visiting under the VWP or a B1/B2 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/is-volunteer-work-allowed-in-the-us-while-visiting-under-the-vwp-or-a-b1-b2-visa)

**2 Application requirements**

[Applying for a USA B1/B2 Visa for an alien resident in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142144/applying-for-a-usa-b1-b2-visa-for-an-alien-resident-in-germany)

*Online visa application*

[Different location for H1B visa than DS160](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141241/different-location-for-h1b-visa-than-ds160)

*Interview and documents*

[What documents should I take to the interview for my US B2 visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/i-am-a-house-wife-planning-to-visit-usa-with-my-husband-holding-b1-b2-visa/142492?noredirect=1#comment353745_142492)

[How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

**3 Requirements for entry/exit**

- [I have an expired US passport, can i enter US on my foreign passport with ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98536/i-have-an-expired-us-passport-can-i-enter-us-on-my-foreign-passport-with-esta)
- [What is the penalty for US citizens entering/leaving the US on a foreign passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85389/what-is-the-penalty-for-us-citizens-entering-leaving-the-us-on-a-foreign-passpor/86059#86059)
- [Customs and luggage clearance, international flights via USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141765/customs-and-luggage-clearance-international-flights-via-usa)
- [Can a US citizen leave and enter the US using a foreign passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51933/can-you-leave-and-enter-the-us-with-a-foreign-passport)
- [Arriving at a different port of entry in the same state in USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62007/arriving-at-a-different-port-of-entry-in-the-same-state-in-usa)

*Visa validity*

[F1 visa for vacation purpose?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140786/f1-visa-for-vacation-purpose)

*Transit*

[Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-transit-or-layover-through-an-american-airport)

[Transiting through the USA with a C1/D](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141526/transiting-through-the-usa-with-a-c1-d)

*Entry/re-entry from neighbouring countries*

[Do I need a passport to return from Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140191/do-i-need-a-passport-to-return-from-canada)

[Does the 90 days VWP rule expire if you travel from the US to Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/does-the-90-days-vwp-rule-expire-if-you-travel-from-the-us-to-canada)

*Calculation of days / I-94 Arrival Departure Record*

[No Until date in USA admit stamp B1/B2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130341/no-until-date-in-usa-admit-stamp-b1-b2)

[What is the minimum wait before I may I re-enter the USA after a 90 day visit on the Visa B-2 Program?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142508/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on)

[Can I enter the US twice within 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141489/can-i-enter-the-us-twice-within-90-days)

[What is the minimum wait before I may re-enter the USA after a 90 day visit on the Visa Waiver Program?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10446/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on)

[I was in the USA three times this year. I am now here traveling for 90 days. Do the previous visits count in the 90 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142140/i-was-in-the-usa-three-times-this-year-i-am-now-here-traveling-for-90-days-do)

[ESTA/WVP - leaving US within 90 days, then staying in DR](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/esta-wvp-leaving-us-within-90-days-then-staying-in-dr)

[Dual citizen of VWP countries and potential re-entry to the US on the other](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138670/dual-citizen-of-vwp-countries-and-potential-re-entry-to-the-us-on-the-other)

**4 Visa refusals**

[B1/B2 US tourist visa refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/b1-b2-us-tourist-visa-refusal?r=SearchResults)

**5 Overstaying**

[Overstayed my visa, left few months after my 18th birthday. Can I go back to visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131508/overstayed-my-visa-left-few-months-after-my-18th-birthday-can-i-go-back-to-vis/131530#131530)

[How does the US know if someone has overstayed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64200/how-does-the-us-know-if-someone-has-overstayed/64207#64207)

[How can a ban from entering the US be lifted?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141364/how-can-a-ban-from-entering-the-us-be-lifted)

**6 Name changes / replacement visas**

[Is it okay to use my US visa after a name change?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65251/is-it-okay-to-use-my-us-visa-after-a-name-change)

[Old Passport with US Visa FNU](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77340/old-passport-with-us-visa-fnu)

[Reissue US, UK, Canada visas in stolen passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142547/reissue-us-uk-canada-visas-in-stolen-passports/142550#142550)