# Can these questions be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question [What documents should I take to the interview for my US B2 visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142490/what-documents-should-i-take-to-the-interview-for-my-us-b2-visa-application) was closed as ‘opinion-based’ but part of it asked for advice on documents to take to the visa interview. Phoog’s answer includes a link to information on the topic which would be useful to others but might get ‘lost’ given the closure.

Similarly, [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country) is a FAQ with a great answer, but it was closed as unclear.

Note: In case anyone wonders why I’m asking, it’s because I‘m drafting a Community Wiki [US visas overview community wiki to avoid duplicates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/us-visas-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates) for duplicate US visa-related questions. I’d like to include these questions in the wiki, but it looks a bit odd because of their closed status.

Comment: These two? ( the ones I have just reopened.)