# Reminder: 95% of all Schengen questions have already been answered

Tags: discussion

I often see [Schengen questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen?sort=newest&pageSize=50) being answered without first checking if a duplicate exists. This harms the structure of the website as instead of linking to a single canonical we're seeing several questions on the same topic with several different answers.

I would therefore like to remind everyone that **95% of all Schengen questions have already been answered** and linked in our [Community Wiki on Schengen questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates). Kindly take a look there before answering a new question and vote to close if a duplicate already exists. If not, post your answer and add that question to the Community Wiki.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean 95% of the ones that have so far been asked?  Surely you aren't claiming that you know how many Schengen questions _could_ be asked.  (Though I wouldn't be surprised at duplicates, as the "suggested duplicate" feature never fails to give me lots of false positives but rarely an actual duplicate).

Comment: @WGroleau I'm saying that on average 95% of all new questions that *we get* are duplicates. Obviously I cannot predict the future but that's a very strong *guess* from seeing hundreds of questions.

Comment: OK, 95% of the new ones.  Got it!

Comment: Maybe y'all could use a mechanism similar to tag warnings but on answers instead of questions? I.e. something like if the question is tagged [tag:schengen] then clicking the answer box will bring up a prompt with a link to the CW you mentioned, and a short message along the lines of this post?

Comment: @E.P. feel free to post this proposal as a separate meta question :)

Comment: @Jonathan I don't know enough about this site to make a proposal that takes site culture into account (or use this site enough to really invest into it), but if you think it's interesting then I'm happy to brainstorm.

Comment: I saw the title and thought: "Only 5% more to go! Let's get going and answer the rest!"